# How to reduce the execution time? ProfileBase's GetPropertyValue takes 40ms to execute

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, webmethod, membership-provider

I have following code, wherein I create list of a custom class using `MembershipUser` array.

Following is the custom class whose list is created:

```
public class userandGroup :IComparable{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int? CompareTo(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj is userandGroup)
            return this.DisplayName.CompareTo((obj as userandGroup).DisplayName);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Following is the code which populates `userlist`:

```
MembershipUserCollection tempuserlist = GetProvider("DefaultProfileProvider", applicationName).GetAllUsers(currentPage - 1, pageSize, out totalUsers);
MembershipUser[] userlist = new MembershipUser[totalUsers];
tempuserlist.CopyTo(userlist, 0);
```

Following is the code which generates list of `userandGroup` (the custom class):

```
foreach (MembershipUser usr in userlist)
    {
        userandGroup usrgp = new userandGroup();
        usrgp.id = ((Guid)usr.ProviderUserKey).ToString() ;
        usrgp.Name = usr.UserName;
        ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(usr.UserName);
        profile.Initialize(usr.UserName, true);
        // Following line approximately takes 40ms per loop.
        usrgp.DisplayName = profile.GetPropertyValue("FirstName").ToString() + " " + profile.GetPropertyValue("LastName").ToString();
        usrgp.type = "user";
        lst.Add(usrgp);
    }
```

As written in the comment, the line;

```
usrgp.DisplayName = profile.GetPropertyValue("FirstName").ToString() + " " + profile.GetPropertyValue("LastName").ToString();
```

takes 40ms to complete in one loop. I have 40 users at the moment. Thus the loop takes approximately 1600ms to execute. If number of users are increased, the loop will take horrendous time to complete.

How can I reduce the execution time of the line or is there any other way to get first name and last name of the user from `ProfileBase`?

Comment: If you feel you've optimized the calls enough and do not care about the order of `lst`, you can always look at processing your users in parallel.

Comment: @TyCobb How to do that? The code sits in a web service which is called synchronously.

Comment: It blocks, but can run many items in your collection at once. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TyCobb, Thanks. That did work. The loop execution time was now reduced to about 750 ms. But I am sure, the loop shouldn't take more than 100 ms to execute. For 40 users, it now takes approx. 750ms, what if I have 1000 or more users?

Comment: Do you really want `CompareTo` to return `0` if the object is not a `userandGroup` (or is `null`)? That means they're equal...

Comment: @RufusL. Thanks for pointing that out. I will change it. Do you have any idea as to how can I reduce the execution time?

Comment: No, this is new to me. How does `FirstName` get set in the first place when you initialize the `profile`? I was just reading the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151825(v=vs.110).aspx) and it looks like you can create a custom class based on `ProfileBase` that has properties you can access by name (instead of reflection), but I don't know understand yet how they get set on `Create`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @TyCobb 's suggestion, I used Parallel Foreach loop. I updated the loop as follows.

```
Object obj = new Object();
    Parallel.ForEach(userlist, (usr) =>
    {
        userandGroup usrgp = new userandGroup();
        usrgp.id = ((Guid)usr.ProviderUserKey).ToString();
        usrgp.Name = usr.UserName;
        ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(usr.UserName);
        profile.Initialize(usr.UserName, true);
        usrgp.type = "user";
        usrgp.DisplayName = profile.GetPropertyValue("FirstName").ToString() + " " + profile.GetPropertyValue("LastName").ToString();
        lock (obj)
        {                
            lst.Add(usrgp);
        }
    });
```

Although this improved performance a bit, the performance is yet not optimum. Now the entire loop completes in less than one second.